# Import Error при запуске celery

Tags: python, celery

У меня есть такая структура папок:

```
- src
     -- \frontend
          --- \views
              ---- tasks.py
      -- \generator
          --- tasks.py
```

Во `frontend/views/tasks` я делаю: `from generator import tasks`.
При запуске селери из папки `views` питон пишет:

> ImportError: No module named generator

В чем причина такой ошибки?

Comment: `__init__.py` в папке `generator` лежит?

Comment: да, init лежит в генераторе

Comment: Какая версия Python?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Родительская директория `generator` обязана быть в `sys.path`, чтобы `from generator import tasks` в этом случае работал.

Достаточно из `src` директории запускать, чтобы путь в PYTHONPATH автоматически добавился:

```
src$ python -m frontend.views.tasks
```

Если хочется запускать из других директорий во время разработки, то можно создать `setup.py`  для каждого пакета и установить их:

```
<top-package-dir>$ pip install -e .
```

---

Не стоит руками изменять `sys.path` в своём коде -- это ведёт к сюрпризам с неочевидным происхождением, например, см. [Traps for the Unwary](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/#traps-for-the-unwary).

Некоторые пакеты автоматически модифицируют `sys.path`, например, `twisted` использует [`_preamble.py`](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/ea2a2000a922f7269060ef9dd9a7db6cd4261ee0/bin/_preamble.py), чтобы скрипты из `bin` директории могли без установки `twisted` пакет найти. Но подобная практика не поощряется, например, Pypy имел в прошлом похожий скрипт [`autopath.py`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/a299cd0a893f/pypy/tool/autopath.py?at=default), но сейчас он больше не используется -- он создаёт больше проблем чем решает.

Пример проблем с импортом: [Why python finds module instead of package if they have the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14183541/4279)